# What is the scheduled launch date history for SLS EM-1?

Tags: falcon-heavy, sls, first-flight

The Falcon Heavy was famous for being "6 months away" for around 6 years, seen in [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skoEE.jpg). How has the SLS maiden launch schedule changed since its first proposed date?

P.S. If someone could generate a chart for SLS like the linked FH one, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: I don't see the "6 months away" for around 6 years in the chart, the mean value of the linear trend line is about 12 months.